# Open a responsive website then print to PDF

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-pfc

Is there a way that I can open a series of webpage URL and loop to print it to pdf?

I tried creating a datawindow and adding ole object control for microsoft web browser, I set the ole object size to display because its responsive and so that I can get all the information before I print. But I am having problems printing the datawindow as it is printing a blank pdf.

Sample links:
just disregard the on demand app error.

[Link1](https://sense-demo.qlik.com/site/sense/app/e76cb407-9047-46fe-be91-11cdffa54918/sheet/ckjSJPd/state/analysis)
[Link2](https://sense-demo.qlik.com/site/sense/app/e76cb407-9047-46fe-be91-11cdffa54918/sheet/anckY/state/analysis)
[Link3](https://sense-demo.qlik.com/site/sense/app/e76cb407-9047-46fe-be91-11cdffa54918/sheet/e02fb88f-5dac-44a0-b5a5-2b8331947f6d/state/analysis)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your PB version?

Comment: I am using pb 12.1.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the Microsoft Web Browser control directly onto a window, load your page, then call the Print method on the ActiveX control directly? You'll need a PDF printer like PrimoPDF.